# How do we disable ctrl-alt-del on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: shutdown, 16.04, reboot, systemd

In previous versions of Ubuntu server, to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> (reboot), we would edit the `/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf` file and change the script to display a message telling that this function won't work any more.

What would be the new way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, now?

Answer (score 13):

In the systemd world, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> is handled by [`ctrl-alt-del.target`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/systemd.special.7.html):

```
ctrl-alt-del.target
   systemd starts this target whenever Control+Alt+Del is pressed on
   the console. Usually, this should be aliased (symlinked) to
   reboot.target.
```

[To disable this target](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53969), do:

```
systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This does not completely disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>. Systemd has a feature where pressing that key combination more than 7 times in 2 seconds triggers an immediate reboot. I'm not sure how to disable it, but I find it useful.

I don't think it can be disabled. From [the systemd manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html):

> `SIGINT`
>
> Upon receiving this signal the systemd system manager will start the
>   `ctrl-alt-del.target` unit. This is mostly equivalent to `systemctl start ctl-alt-del.target`. If this signal is received more than 7
>   times per 2s, an immediate reboot is triggered. Note that pressing
>   Ctrl-Alt-Del on the console will trigger this signal. Hence, if a
>   reboot is hanging, pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del more than 7 times in 2s is a
>   relatively safe way to trigger an immediate reboot.
>
> systemd user managers treat this signal the same way as `SIGTERM`.