# How do we disable ctrl-alt-del on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

How do I disable Ctrl-Alt-Del logout in Ubuntu 20.04?

I followed this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763887/how-do-we-disable-ctrl-alt-del-on-ubuntu-16-04) using these commands:

```
systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
systemctl daemon-reload
```

However, the key combination is still working afterward.

The reason I'd like it disabled is because my keyboard & mouse is shared between my Linux machine and a Windows machine that requires Ctrl-Alt-Del to unlock. If my keyboard is accidentally still connected to my Linux machine, it will logout.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del have you tried to remove it from key combo? https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1hcQ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open "Settings - Keyboard Shortcuts". Look up the entry "Log out" under the "System" section, and disable the keybinding. That works by clicking the line, then hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in the "Set Shortcut" dialog. Then click "Set" to apply the setting and close the dialog.